# Difficulties adding onclick to a link with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a script that makes that makes a tile for every item in an XML-file. The tile is a div inside an "a" tag created by javascript.

```
document.getElementById('Body').appendChild(tileLink);
tileLink.appendChild(tile);
tile.appendChild(tileTitle);
tile.appendChild(tileImg);
document.write(" ");
```

So when tileLink is clicked a javascript function "showDiv(divId)" has to be loaded. divId is a variable in the script needed to load the function.
I've tried these 2 lines but with both the script doesn't work and no objects are loaded.

```
tileLink.onclick = showDiv(divId);
textLink.addEventListener("click", showDiv(divId));
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle or show all your code? HTML and JS.

Comment: Note the 2nd half of the accepted answer on the duplicate.  If anyone has a better close candidate do let me know (there must be one) so I can favorite it and use it instead in the future.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=xBu2CEebSb

Answer (score 3):

Event handlers require function references. By invoking the function, you are immediately executing it.

```
textLink.addEventListener("click", function() {
    showDiv(divId);
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work either...

Comment: If I do this, only the last item is shown

Comment: Well then you need to adjust it to accommodate the item list -- which was not a part of your question.